# Making a baseline table with loops, is there a better way to do this?

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to construct a table with baseline data. I have a dataframe containing measurements of 5000 persons over 6 different rounds. Per round I have approximately 1000 measurements. The columns are named according to variable and round, e.g. `cylr1` `cylr2` `cylr3`. I have continuous, categorical and dichotomous data. I need mean/sd or amount and percentage per group for these data, split by a category of interest and round of measurement.

I managed to do this by writing a set of loops inside a function, allowing me to create the table i need for any variable of interest. However, it is quite a large function, which takes some time to process. Below an example adapted to `mtcars`, to show what the structure looks like. I mostly use to things, `grep` to get the colnames, regardless of the round it is in, and loops to iterate through separate rounds and levels. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

```
data(mtcars)
mtcars$am <- mtcars$am + 1
mtcarsr1 <- mtcars
colnames(mtcarsr1) <- paste0(colnames(mtcarsr1),"r1")
mtcarsr1 <- subset(mtcarsr1, select = -mpgr1)
mtcarsr2 <- mtcars
colnames(mtcarsr2) <- paste0(colnames(mtcarsr2),"r2")
mtcarsr3 <- mtcars
colnames(mtcarsr3) <- paste0(colnames(mtcarsr3),"r3")
vec <- c(rep(1,8), rep(2,8), rep(3,8), rep(4,8))
mtcarsrounds <- data.frame(vec, mtcarsr1, mtcarsr2, mtcarsr3)


# variable: category to sort by
# niveaus: number of levels within category
baseline.cars <- function(variable, niveaus){
  # Make separate dataframe per level of the category of intereset
  base <- list()
  for (i in 1:niveaus){
    base.loop <- mtcarsrounds[variable == i,]
    base.loop <- base.loop[grep("carb|disp|drat|vs|mpg", colnames(base.loop))]
    base[[i]] <- base.loop
  }

  # For all categories, place data from rounds in separate dataframe
  base.ronde <- list()
  base.base <- list()
  for (j in 1:niveaus){
    for (t in 1:3){
      base.loop <- base[[j]][grep(paste0("r",t), colnames(base[[j]]))]
      base.ronde[[t]] <- base.loop
      base.base[[j]] <- base.ronde
    }
  } 


  # Perform necessary counts and calculations per variable for baseline characteristics
  # tryCatch{} functions ignore errors when variable isn't measured in certain rounds
  # if{} functions convert NULL values caused by tryCatch{} to NA, so they can be included in dataframes
  # if{} wrapper around whole loop is to ignore errors caused by empty categories
  base.loop <- list()
  base.desc <- list()
  for (j in 1:niveaus){
    for (t in 1:3){
      if (nrow(base.base[[j]][[t]]) > 0){
        carb1p <- round(sum(!is.na(base.base[[j]][[t]][grep("carb", colnames(base.base[[j]][[t]]))]) & base.base[[j]][[t]][grep("carb", colnames(base.base[[j]][[t]]))] == 1)/
                          length(!is.na(base.base[[j]][[t]][grep("carb", colnames(base.base[[j]][[t]]))])),2)            
        carb1 <- sum(!is.na(base.base[[j]][[t]][grep("carb", colnames(base.base[[j]][[t]]))]) & base.base[[j]][[t]][grep("carb", colnames(base.base[[j]][[t]]))] == 1)
        disp.mean <- round(sapply(base.base[[j]][[t]][grep("disp", colnames(base.base[[j]][[t]]))], mean, na.rm = TRUE),1)
        disp.sd <- round(sapply(base.base[[j]][[t]][grep("disp", colnames(base.base[[j]][[t]]))], sd, na.rm = TRUE),1)
        mpg.mean <- tryCatch({mpg.mean <- round(sapply(base.base[[j]][[t]][grep("mpg", colnames(base.base[[j]][[t]]))],mean, na.rm = TRUE),1) }, error = function (e){})
        mpg.sd <- tryCatch({mpg.sd <- round(sapply(base.base[[j]][[t]] 
                 [grep("mpg", colnames(base.base[[j]][[t]]))], sd, na.rm = 
                 TRUE),1)}, error = function (e){})
        if (is.null(mpg.mean)) {mpg.mean <- NA}
        if (is.null(mpg.sd)) {mpg.sd <- NA}
        base.loop[[t]] <- data.frame(carb1, carb1p, carb2, carb2p,
                 disp.mean, disp.sd, mpg.mean, mpg.sd)
          }
        }
        base.desc[[j]] <- base.loop
      }

      # Combine dataframes from separate rounds together
      for (i in 1:length(base.desc)){
        base.desc[[i]] <- rbind(base.desc[[i]][[1]], base.desc[[i]][[2]], 
        base.desc[[i]][[3]])
        rownames(base.desc[[i]]) <- c("Ronde 1","Ronde 2","Ronde 3")
      }

      print(base.desc)
    }

    # Run the function
    baseline.cars(mtcarsrounds$vec, 4)
```

Edit: shortened it down

Comment: You seem to have understood the concept of a "reproducible example". Now you need to work on understanding the concept of a "minimal example".

Comment: I tried to incorporate all three of the data types I have, to make it as representative as possible. I see now that that maybe wasn't necessary, I'll edit it.

Comment: Use tableone (https://github.com/kaz-yos/tableone) or some alternatives.